# How to test a vitual pure function in C++ and Google Test?

Tags: c++, googletest

Edited as requested, e.1 :

I am stuck on this :

I need to test a virtual pure function in Google Test and i cannot get it to work. I keep getting this error in the fixture "ReferenceTest a:" : The type 'ReferenceTest' must implement the inherited pure virtual method 'Bibli::Reference::clone'. This error may be trivial but i just don't see it.

Thank you for your help.

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <Date.h> 
#include <Reference.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace Bibli;

//********************IMPLANTATION D'UNE CLASSE CONCRETE***********************

class ReferenceTest: public Reference {

public:
ReferenceTest(const std::string& p_cote,
        const std::string& p_theme,
        const std::string& p_titre,
        const std::string& p_auteurs,
        int p_anneeEdition,
        const util::Date& p_dateAcquisition)
:
Reference(p_cote, p_theme, p_titre, p_auteurs, p_anneeEdition, p_dateAcquisition)
{}; //instancier un objet Reference

ReferenceTest(std::istream& p_is)
:
    Reference(p_is)
{};

virtual void afficher(std::ostream& os) const
{}; // Doit être implantée car la classe est concrète


virtual std::string reqReferenceFormate() const
{
    return Reference::reqReferenceFormate();
};

virtual Reference* clone() const
{
    //return new ReferenceTest(*this);
    return 0;
};

~ReferenceTest();

};

//*********************************FIXTURES************************************

//*****************************************************************************
//  Fixture UneReference pour la création d'un objet Reference afin d'instancier
//  une Reference de test
// ****************************************************************************

class UneReference : public ::testing::Test
{
public:

UneReference()
:
    a("121a", "Informatique", "A Book of Jokes", "Mister Faynman", 2005, util::Date(8, 4, 2013))
{};

ReferenceTest a;

};
```

and  my Reference.h :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

#include "ContratException.h"
#include "ValidationFormat.h"
#include "Date.h"

namespace Bibli
{
class Reference
{
private:
        std::string m_cote;
        std::string m_theme;
        std::string m_titre;
        std::string m_auteurs;
        int m_anneeEdition;
        util::Date m_dateAcquisition;
        void verifieInvariant() const;
public:
// Constructeur
Reference(
const std::string& p_cote,
const std::string& p_theme,
const std::string& p_titre,
const std::string& p_auteurs,
int p_anneeEdition,
const util::Date& p_dateAcquisition);

virtual ~Reference(){};

//Constructeur avec flux d'entrée de la classe. On construit un objet Reference à partir
//de données provenant d'un flux d'entrée. Toutes les données sont supposées valides.
Reference(std::istream& p_is);

bool operator ==(const Reference& uneReference);

virtual std::string reqReferenceFormate() const = 0;
//Le fait de mettre = 0; déclare cette fonction comme étant pur.
//On ne peut plus créer d'objet de cette classe.

virtual Reference* clone() const = 0; //IMPORTANT DE METTRE FONCTIONNEL PLUS TARD

// Fonction d'acquisition des données
//! \fn inline std::string reqCote() const
//! \brief Méthode d'accès au données
//! \return m_cote
inline std::string reqCote() const
{
    return m_cote;
}
//! \fn inline std::string reqTheme() const
//! \brief Méthode d'accès aux données
//! \return m_theme
inline std::string reqTheme() const
{
    return m_theme;
}
//! \fn inline std::string reqTitre() const
//! \brief Méthode d'accès au données
//! \return m_titre
inline std::string reqTitre() const
{
    return m_titre;
}
//! \fn inline std::string reqAuteurs() const
//! \brief Methode d'acces au donnees
//! \return m_auteurs
inline std::string reqAuteurs() const
{
    return m_auteurs;
}
//! \fn inline int reqAnneeEdition() const
//! \brief M√ethode d'acces aux donnees
//! \return m_anneeEdition
inline int reqAnneeEdition() const
{
    return m_anneeEdition;
}
//! \fn inline std::string reqDateAcquisition() const
//! \brief Méthode d'accès au données
//! \return m_dateAcquisition
inline util::Date reqDateAcquisition() const
{
    return m_dateAcquisition;
}
//! \fn inline void asgTheme(const std::string& p_theme)
//! \param[in] p_theme Recoit la nouvelle valeur du theme
//! \brief Change la valeur du th√®me
inline void asgTheme(const std::string& p_theme)
{
    m_theme = p_theme;
}
};
}//----namespace Bibli
```

the source code compiles just fine and it works for the main app. But every time i have ReferenceTest in the tests :

```
ReferenceTest a = ReferenceTest(p_cote, p_theme, p_titre, p_auteurs, p_anneeEdition, p_dateAcquisition);
```

it is underlined with this error message in Eclipse :

```
The type 'ReferenceTest' must implement the inherited pure virtual method 'Bibli::Reference::clone'
```

and the compiler, now, gives me this error :

```
"vtable for ReferenceTest", referenced from:
  ReferenceTest::ReferenceTest(std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)in ReferenceTesteur.o

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [TestReference.exe] Error 1
```

I know this is related to my virtual functions but i don't know what.

Comment: I don't see it either. Are you sure the error refers to `clone` (which you appear to be overriding) and not `reqReferenceFormate` (which you apparently aren't)?

Answer (score 2):

Your updated question indicates that the "must implement the inherited pure virtual method" error is a spurious message generated by your IDE, not a compiler error. Since the second error comes from the linker, after successful compilation, this cannot be a real error. I'm afraid I can't help you with fixing the IDE's error detection.

The linker error referring to the missing vtable is because you declare, but don't define, a destructor for the derived class. It looks like the derived class doesn't need to do anything in its destructor, so just remove the declaration `~ReferenceTest();`

Comment: Thank you Mike. The destructor was indeed unnecessary and the linker error was related to some libraries and variables needed by Google Test (pthread, gtest, gtest_main). They were missing in Paths and Symbol Properties in my Eclipse config.